# Creating different templates for each user for emails and reports on Node/Express/React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am currently developing a React based web app with a Node/Express backend that will act as a management system for many of my clients which are small businesses. This system will contain your typical things like work orders, invoices, customers, etc. There are many scenarios where the system will need to generate either printed output or an email based on the information inside the system. However, the problem I am trying to solve is how to customize the templates for each user that may be printed or emailed.

For example, user A and user B both want to print a copy of the work order. User A wants to include individual details for each item on the work order such as the description, and price. User B does not want to include the price, and wants to place a written guarantee in the footer.

Ideally, the users would be able to use a drag and drop/rich text editor and arrange, add/remove, and customize the template as needed with the configuration stored as a JSON or similar. I would not have to create multiple templates and nothing would be hardcoded.

There is a package `react-jsonschema-form` which borders my use case but is more focused on form generation. However, the idea around `formData` being used to build the output is very similar to what I am looking to do. It looks like I may be able to leverage Pug or Handlebars to attempt this, but it seems counterintuitive to use 2 templating engines.

Are there any existing packages that tackle what I am looking to do? Unfortunately, I've had very little luck finding anything, and coding a framework to tackle this issue would drastically delay my timeline.

Comment: Maybe just as food for thought: We had similar (but maybe somewhat more complex) requirements and ended up allowing users to configure their own JasperReports document templates for which there is a standalone graphical editor – since the layout of documents is not a very simple endeavour. For text-only emails a (rich-text) editor and some pre-defined placeholders may be good enough. To me these would be two separate questions though.